# Clarification on Static and Primitives

Tags: c#, java, oop, scala, static

Static and primitives are not part of OOPs.  I have read that static and primitives are not allowed in scala class definitions. If this is true, then why static and primitives were allowed in java and in c# and few other languages?

Comment: @suresh is that rational design to add something which is not part of OOP?

Comment: Yes ,so as to improve the performance of the language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not part of "pure" Object Oriented, but sometimes "pure" gets in the way of "getting the job done".

Using primitives can make mathematical operations (in particular) much faster, and statics enable a lot of useful design patterns.

Comment: Truth be told, they could also be described as optimization at an inappropriate level of abstraction. Primitive wrappers could also have been used throughout the language and unboxed into primitives at JIT-compile time where appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

C#, C++ and Java are a general purpose programming languages. You can find for example elements of duck-typing in C# 4.0, elements of functional programming, and many more useful constructs.

Not every program and not every part of a program has to be object oriented. Use OOP when needed and when it serves purpose, in C#, C++ and Java you can use other or simpler constructs every time you feel OOP is a '*firing mosquito with a cannon*'.

Answer (score 1):

Its an engineering decision. Like most engineering decisions it involves carefully balancing lots of different forces on the design.  In this case its the design of the language. Different languages are intended to solve different problems and have different objectives.  So its not surprising that different languages come to different conclusions.

It this case there are costs and benefits to having primitives.

Primitives can be faster.
Primitives can make it easer to do certain low level things (eg writing individual bits to a register on a micro condoler in an embedded system.)

On the other hand primitives can make your programming language more complicated as your primitive types have different syntax etc to operate on them. Some newer languages are trying to have there cake and eat it by using primitive types under the covers but making them look like objects in terms of syntax.